# Is there a g.projector overlay with all world's administrative regions?

Tags: cartography

I'm searching for an overlay for [g.projector](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/gprojector/help/) including all (or most) of the world's administrative regions. (apparently, valid formats are CNO, CNOB and SHP)

With "administrative region" I mean the administrative level just below the nation level, such as US States, UK Regions, etc.

I've found some nation-specific ones [at statsilk](http://www.statsilk.com/maps/download-free-shapefile-maps#download-country-shapefile-maps), but they aren't many, and they are a single file for each nation, so I wouldn't even know how to import it in g.projector…

How can I find such a file, assuming it exists?

Consider that I'm pretty new at this, so it's possible I'm missing something obvious. I've searched on google, following many links, browsing many sites, and noticed there are **many** different maps… only I couldn't find that one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Natural Earth Cultural layers](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) - I suspect that you want `Admin 1 – States, Provinces`.

Comment: (for some reason, it won't let me accept @iant's answer, nor let me comment, nor let me flag anything… If moderators have a way to mark it as accepted, please do so. Thanks)

Comment: @MipMap you need to log in as the same user as you posted the question (this answer, although with the same name, is a different user).  Once you log in you should be able to comment on this question and accept the answer.

Comment: I can't actually get the naturalearthdata shp files to display as overlays in G.Projector (v2.1.7) although I am able to get shp files to display from other sources such as the statsilk ones. Did they work for anyone else? Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: If you have a new question please ask using the ask button